# How to access the axes of each widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I use the scroll bar for the chart. When adding a second and subsequent graph, the bars do not scroll through the new graphs.

And when deleting new charts, an error occurs when trying to scroll.

I understand that need to have separate access to each chart, but I don't know how to do it?

I assume that need to have access to "self._chart.axis" to all graphs, via an array.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart
import math


mas =[1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.65, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 2.3, 1.5, 1.35, 2.52, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
              1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.7, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
              1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1]
x = len(mas)
x_ = x - 1

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, start = 1, parent=None):
        self.start = start
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.step = 30

        self.scrollbar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
            sliderMoved=self.onAxisSliderMoved,
            pageStep=self.step,
        )
        self.scrollbar.setRange(0, x_)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.open = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.open.setText("Open")
        self.open.clicked.connect(self.open_clicked)

        self.close = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.close.setText("Close")
        self.close.clicked.connect(self.close_clicked)

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.open)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.close)

        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        self.lay.insertLayout(0, self.hbox)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.splitter, stretch=1)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.scrollbar)

        self.open_clicked()

    def open_clicked(self):
        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self._chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self._line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()
        for i in range(0, len(mas)):
            self._line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, mas[i]))
        self._chart.addSeries(self._line_serie)
        self._chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self._chart_view.setChart(self._chart)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self._chart_view)

    def close_clicked(self):
        count = self.splitter.count()
        if count > 1:
            w = self.splitter.widget(count - 1)
            if w is not None:
                w.deleteLater()


    def adjust_axes(self, value_min, value_max):
        if value_min >= 0 and value_max >= 0 and value_max <= x_ and value_max > value_min:
            self._chart.axisX(self._line_serie).setRange(value_min, value_max)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onAxisSliderMoved(self, value):
        value2 = value + self.step
        value1 = value
        if value2 >= x_:
            value2 = x_
            value1 = value2 - self.step
        self.adjust_axes(math.floor(value1), math.ceil(value2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow(start = 0)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why are you still using the same instance attributes (`self._chart_view`, `self._chart`, etc) to create new objects each time? The previous answer already explained to you that it's *not* a good approach, as it always overwrites the same attribute with new objects, while loosing direct references to the previous ones. Please, do not just copy, paste and adapt code that is given in answers. Read the code, study it, and *understand* what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is similar to your previous post: If you use the same variable to reference several objects then the variable only refers to the last object, therefore when deleting that object and wanting to delete the returned object the application crashes. The solution is to use the splitter to iterate over the QChartView, and using that information get the QChart and QLineSeries:

```
def open_clicked(self):
    chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
    chart = QtChart.QChart()
    line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()
    for i, value in enumerate(mas):
        line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, value))
    chart.addSeries(line_serie)
    chart.createDefaultAxes()
    chart_view.setChart(chart)
    self.splitter.addWidget(chart_view)
```

```
def adjust_axes(self, value_min, value_max):
    for i in range(self.splitter.count()):
        chart_view = self.splitter.widget(i)
        if isinstance(chart_view, QtChart.QChartView):
            chart = chart_view.chart()
            for serie in chart.series():
                chart.axisX(serie).setRange(value_min, value_max)
```

Comment: Thank you, eyllanesc!
The fact that there is no object and therefore an error after deletion, I realized.
I didn't understand how to access each "chart" programmatically.

Comment: I wanted to ask why "chart", "chart_view" without self. Is it so that don't have access to them?

Comment: @inquirer What is the goal of "self"? If you don't know, check your notes about OOP or search SO as that question has already been answered.